# Apache2 change "root directory"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, apache2.4

First of all, I do not know what the result I'm looking for is called, therefore I have no idea what to search for!
So I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate.

I'd like to have my server react based on the url. I already know how I add subdomains and change the directory.

http://www.example.com --> /var/www/domain.com/html

http://sub.example.com --> /var/www/sub/html

This here is what I'm trying to achieve:

http://sub.example.com/foo --> /var/www/sub/foo/html

http://sub.example.com/bar --> /var/www/domain.com/bar/html

I chose these because I think that they are showing perfectly what I'm trying to achieve. Again, I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate!

Thanks for your help!

PS. no comment will be downvoted by me :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've been looking for Alias.

examples:
Alias "/foo" "/var/www/sub/foo/html"
Alias "/bar" "/var/www/domain.com/bar/html"

it's simple... when you've found (by accident) what you are looking for :)